# Differential equation Fourier series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

I am having trouble figuring out how to solve this problem using the Fourier series method. I'm not allowed to use methods of undetermined coefficient or variation of parameter.
$$
y'' + 2y' + y = 25\cos(2t)
$$
The general solution is obvious but I'm unable to find the particular solution. I tried to use the Fourier series representation of $25\cos(2t)$ but I get 0 for my $a_0$, $a_n$, and $b_n$. The only value that's not 0 is when my $n=2$, then my value becomes $25$.

In the book I use, this is called the steady state solution and Theorem 1 is called Forced Oscillation.  I'm unable to apply the theorem because I am unable to obtain the Fourier coefficients.

Solution:
$$
ce^{-t} + dte^{-t}  -3\cos(2t)+4\sin(2t)
$$

Comment: If $a_n$ and $b_n$ are the coefficients of the $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms in the Fourier series expansion, it makes sense that $a_n = b_n = 0$ for all $n\ne 2$, does it not?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The idea is to assume that
$$
y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left[ a_n \sin(nx) + b_n \cos(nx)\right]
$$
Now compute $y', y''$ and equate it to the right-hand side to get a recurrence relationship for $a_n$ and $b_n$ which you can solve.

Comment: I'm not sure that's how I'm supposed to solve the problem. https://books.google.com/books?id=t8BeDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=theorem+1+forced+oscillations+asmar&source=bl&ots=ty0w9FW5S_&sig=1eLTou3LlzKr6oKVcc9_6TEfznQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDvvPW9L7WAhUBnxQKHSaHAq0Q6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=theorem%201%20forced%20oscillations%20asmar&f=false      Look at page 70. The formula there is the one I'm supposed to use to solve the problem.

Comment: @HelpMe on pp.69-70 it seems to describe exactly the approach i advised you to take and Theorem 1 is really the final result of that approach. Knowing that will save you the arithmetic. Why don't you simply plug in?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't practicing the wrong method.